# In my Jersey-based REST client, should I access and close() the Response reachable from a WebApplicationException?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am using the [Jersey client API](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html) to write a REST client.

JAX-RS' [`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html) defines a [`getResponse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html#getResponse--) method.

Since [`Response`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) objects [should be closed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#close--) in general, does that mean I should call [`getResponse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html#getResponse--) on [`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html)  instances that I would otherwise let fly? Surely not?

Comment: There's no connection tied to that response, so there's nothing to close. Technically it would be an outgoing response. Only inbound responses need to be close as they are tied to the connection.

Comment: Are you sure? From the [`close()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#close--) documentation: "The close() method should be invoked on all instances that contain an un-consumed entity input stream to ensure the resources associated with the instance are properly cleaned-up and prevent potential memory leaks. *This is typical for client-side scenarios where application layer code processes only the response headers and ignores the response entity.*" I may just be too cautious here!

Comment: Think about when then the WebApplicationException is created, and when the actual Response object is created. If you look at it this way, you will understand my argument. I guess the documentation doesn't differentiate between outgoing and incoming, but there is a huge difference between them, even though it's the same API

Comment: Check the actual class of the response instance. If it's an outbound response, you most likely don't need to close it. If it's an inbound response, then you probably do. I may be wrong in assuming it _will_ be an outgoing response when talking about the client side

Comment: @peeskillet: Thanks. For clarity, this is when one does: `builder.get(JsonObject.class)` or the equivalent, so the `Response` is automatically created by the client framework (Jersey must create the `Response` first, and then wrap it in a `WebApplicationException`). So I guess I could see it going either way? Perhaps creating the `Response` leaves its associated `InputStream` in an unconsumed state? Then you could see how I might be uneasy not closing it.

Comment: Honestly I have never encountered having to deal with a WebApplicationException on the client side, so I am not sure how/when it created. What I mean by outgoing and incoming, is that the response when obtained through the client like `target.request().get()`, will be an incoming response. With Jersey, the implementation class will be `InboundJaxrsResponse`. On the server when you do `Respons.ok().build()`, the returned instance will be `OutboundJaxrsResponse`. On the server, that response is not tied to any connection.

Comment: Usually on the server side when you want to create your own WebApplicationException, you would instantiate it with an _outbound_ response. But in the case of the client, I am not sure. For all I know the client will instantiate with the incoming response. But now that I think about it, it would make a lot more sense for the client the instantiate it with the inbound response, instead of creating an outbound response. So maybe you should close it. Like I said, just check the actual type of the response

Comment: This [link to Bill Burke's JAX-RS 2.0 book](https://books.google.com/books?id=wzkYAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA118&dq=%22in+this+example,+we+invoke+an+http+get+to+obtain+a+response+object.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC5JDC_M7NAhVG9GMKHRKqA6cQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22in%20this%20example%2C%20we%20invoke%20an%20http%20get%20to%20obtain%20a%20response%20object.%22&f=false) seems to indicate that calling `close()` is almost always a good idea, so that's what I'll do.

Comment: I think the reason I have never had to deal with the WebApplicationException on the client side, is that I always the Response object from the client, instead of trying to get the response as an entity. In my opinion, this is better practice. That's just my opinion. I always do my status checks with the response before I try and get the entity.